# Solve the following trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

$\sec x = -2$

Solve the equation algebraically, where $x$ is greater than or equal to $0$ degrees, and less than $360$ degrees

I need to give my answer as an exact solution

Here is what I have done so far:

\begin{align*}
\sec & = 1/\cos\\
\cos & =-1/2
\end{align*}

Using the $30$-$60$-$90$ triangle, we see that $\cos \pi/3 = -1/2$

So, does $x = \pi/3$?

How do I know if there is more than one solution in this domain? And, when I substituted $x= \pi/3$ into the original equation, I got $2$, instead of $-2$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\cos(\pi/3) = 1/2$ not $-1/2$. But $\cos(2 \pi/3)=\cos(4\pi/3)=-1/2$

Comment: Okay- so then what is x if cosx=-1/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did all the algebra right to get to the point $\cos(x) = \frac{-1}{2}$. By referring to the unit circle
http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/images/circle-unit-304560.gif
 you'll see that $\cos(x) = \frac{-1}{2}$ precisely when $x \in \{120^\circ, 240^\circ\}$

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't realize that I the unit circle would help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! The unit circle was drilled into my head back in high school. It can be useful to know on the fly, but it's also not too hard to derive whatever values you need.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos \theta$ is the $x$-coordinate of the point on the unit circle that is an angle of $\theta$ away from $(1,0)$.

So if you want to solve $\cos\theta=-1/2$, you're looking for points on the unit circle that are also on the vertical line $x=-1/2$. Draw a sketch; there are two of them.

In this particular case you can find the exact angles by contemplating the equilateral triangle with corners at $(0,0)$, $(-1,0)$ and $(-\frac12,\frac{\sqrt3}2)$.

Answer (score 0):

since $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ we want $\cos(x)=\frac{-1}{2}$. So $x=120$ or $240$ degrees

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way you could include a bit more detail as to how you reached 210 and 240?

Comment: @MM98: I think 210° was "reached" by mistyping the correct value of 120°.

Comment: Don't they force you to learn a table with what are deemed "important" values of the cosine function in your school?

Comment: Oh dang, my bad I'm so sorry. Thank you @HenningMakholm